# Karush-Kuhn-Tucker Conditions in a Biometrics Research Paper

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, computer-vision

For one of my course works I'm supposed to find a scientific paper from my field of research that involves an optimisation problem solution based on the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions.

My research field is computer vision and more specifically ocular biometrics. I've found [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.02025.pdf) from the general field of deep learning, but haven't been able to find anything from a more specific field. Is anyone aware of any such paper from biometrics or at least CV-based identity recognition in general?